# NodeJs Server on production

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, nginx

So i made a simply express server connected with a database. On localhost it connects with database perfectly but on deployment it shows an error like that

{"code":"ESOCKET","originalError":{"code":"ESOCKET"},"name":"ConnectionError"}

On sql Server everything is set perfectly.

my configuration looks like that:

```
const config={
    user: 'xxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxxxx',
    server: 'public_ip_from_sql', 
    database: 'data_base',
    debug:true,
    port: 1433,
    client:"mssql",
    options: {
        encrypt: false,
        enableArithAbord:true,
        trustServerCertificate: true,
        validateBulkLoadParameters:true,
        },
    connectionTimeout:150000,
    pool:{
        max:10,
        min:0,
        idleTimeoutMillis:3000
    }
}
```

I am hosting it on Plesk nginx server. i havent find any solution to solve this problem.

Comment: On the target server have you gone to SQL Server Configuration Manager > Server Protocols and enabled the TCP/IP protocol? Is it configured to listen on the public IP address via port 1433? Does Windows Firewall with Advanced Security allow incoming connection to tcp/1433 from your Plesk server's public IP address?

Comment: Aside... `enableArithAbord:true` should probably be `enableArithAbort:true`.

Comment: Yes i have allowed every request in this port thats why i can connect on localhost via public Ip

Comment: `localhost` is not your public IP, it's `127.0.0.1` when using IPv4 and `::1` when using IPv6.

Comment: I am not using this on Database only on server in Node when i was developed it in Database i am using Public Ip like 94.xx.x.xxx

Comment: You have hosted nodejs app on Plesk and your SQL Server on your PC?

Comment: So to be clear plesk is a host provider that you can host you apps online. Sql Database that i was trying to connect was hosted on actuall server in the company that i work. The issue solved by changing Host Provider i create a Heroku app that on one specific directory that connect to that Database